# Rails 5.2 Rake Task Not Sending Mailer (Despite inner mailer working perfectly)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, actionmailer, rake-task

I have the following mailer set up in a rake task in `lib/tasks/scheduler.rake`:

```
  desc "Send capsule reminder emails"
  task send_capsule_reminders: :environment do
    require 'time'
    t = Time.now.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)").next_day
    month = t.month
    day = t.day
    Capsule.all.each do |capsule|
      if month == capsule.capsule_date.month && day == capsule.capsule_date.day && capsule.active && capsule.reminder_email
        NewCapsuleReminderMailer.send_capsule_reminder_email(capsule).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

I have tested `NewCapsuleReminderMailer.send_capsule_reminder_email(capsule).deliver` from my console and it sends the mailer correctly.

I checked and `month == capsule.capsule_date.month` and `day == capsule.capsule_date`.  Also `capsule.active` is `true` as is `capsule.reminder_email`.

However, when I run `rake send_capsule_reminders` nothing happens.

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't sending and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `NewCapsuleReminderMailer.send_capsule_reminder_email(capsule).deliver` should be `NewCapsuleReminderMailer.send_capsule_reminder_email(capsule).deliver_now`.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Such a simple change!  Thank you!